# Не выбрасывается исключение IndexError

Tags: python, исключения

Нет вывода по `IndexError`:

```python
coffee = ["Café Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Espresso", "Cappuccino", "Macchiato"]
choice = int(input())
try:
    for i in range(len(coffee)):
        if i == choice:
            print(coffee[i])    
except IndexError:
    print('invalid number')
finally:
    print('Have a good day')
```

Comment: А почему такой вывод должен быть?

Comment: Исключение возникает, если что-то идёт не так. Прочитайте, что это вообще такое, прежде чем использовать. Продумайте логику своего кода. Запустите отладку по шагам, если затрудняетесь. Здесь и не должно возникать `IndexError`, ему просто неоткуда взяться, т.к. логика Вашего кода предусматривает проверку на равенство и в случае неудачи просто не обращается к индексу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вашем коде блок except не будет вызван, т.к. Вы сначала получаете длину списка, а потом сравниваете со значением. Для получения сообщения Вам нужно получить ошибку:

```
coffee = ["Café Latte", "Caffe Americano", "Espresso", "Cappuccino", "Macchiato"]
choice = int(input())

try:
    print(coffee[choice])    
except IndexError:
    print('invalid number')
finally:
    print('Have a good day')
```

Comment: Да, теперь ясно. Я же не получал ошибку в запросе. Спасибо за ответ.